# Laravel: Extending different layouts inside if-else condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to extend different layouts inside if-else statement.
Here is my code:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    @extends('layouts.adminPanel')
@else
    @extends('layouts.home')
@endif
```

But the view files extending both layouts. No matter user logged in or not!

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add Extends at the first line

```
@extends(\Auth::check() ? 'layouts.adminPanel' : 'layouts.home')
```