# Determine the layout per user level/role on Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Good day
I have 3 differentes levels/roles in my project
admin
employment
customer

I want to determine the layout for one page depending on the level, this is my code, I use Auth::user

```
@if(Auth::user()->role === 'employment')
    @extends('layouts.menuemployments')
@elseif (Auth::user()->role === 'admin')
    @extends('layouts.menuadmin')
@elseif(Auth::user()->role === 'customer')
    @extends('layouts.menucustomer')
@endif
```

But when I try this, the code show me the 3 menus, what is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: Extending different layouts inside if-else condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369169/laravel-extending-different-layouts-inside-if-else-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sample code.

```
@php
   if(Auth::user()->role === 'employment') {
      $layoutDirectory = 'layouts.menuemployments';
   } elseif (Auth::user()->role === 'admin') {
      $layoutDirectory = 'layouts.menuadmin';
   } else {
      $layoutDirectory = 'layouts.menucustomer';
   }
@endphp

@extends($layoutDirectory)
```

Of course it can be improved by moving the `@php` block in the middleware to make it a lot more cleaner

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware