# Laravel Layout For Different Users

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a few layouts in my Laravel app but the most common is  and .

I have a shared route / view for the settings and password pages but want to use the same view inside different layouts depending on suer type.

**/password - password.blade.php**

```
@if(Auth::user()->type == 'business')
<x-business-layout>
@else
<x-app-layout>
@endif
    

    PAGE CONTENT HERE


@if(Auth::user()->type == 'business')
</x-business-layout>
@else
</x-app-layout>
@endif
```

This is how I thought I could dynamically change the layout depending on user but it doesn't work. Just get `syntax error, unexpected 'else'` at the end of the file where I use that code again to close the layout off.

Any ways to do this?

Comment: Try `<x-business-layout/>` in case it needs well formatted XML

Comment: @apokryfos Im ending the layout tags like that at the bottom of the file already :)

Comment: You can't do that. It needs to open and close within the if or else block. You can look at what markup it generates if you check the cache files in `storage/framework/views`

Comment: @apokryfos yea and I'm looking for a solution around that so I dont have to duplicate the page content into two parts of the if statement. I'll update the question to show the code better.

Comment: Are you sure your sections are properly closed? With the code you posted as is, I don't see how are you getting a syntax error.

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy yep positive. even removed all content from between the code posted so my file is exactly like the code above and the error still happens.

Comment: Could you please share your `<x-business-layout>` component?

Comment: I believe the issue with the code is somewhere there.

Comment: What if you try : replacing your if/else/endif by normal php tags `<?php ?>` and see if that helps you debug, also try removing the else and replace by if/endif if/endif

Comment: @BradAndrews but if I remove the if statments and just use <x-business-layout> CONTENT </x-business-layout> then the page works. Both layouts work fine, the error only appears when I use an if statment around them.

Comment: It's just a theory, but it could be that something inside your layout file, is not set correctly. Would explain why it works fine with no if statements, but breaks when you add them... Like your code is trying to do something, then you stop the execution of the code prematurely, by the use of if statements, which then returns `unexpected else` error that you see.

Comment: You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52940742/determine-the-layout-per-user-level-role-on-laravel-5-7) in laravel 5.7 example

Comment: I would try to  combine middleware with data sharing for all views (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) and make the tag itself dynamic as in `<{{ $x-layout }}-layout>`. Your approach doesn't work because the Blade translation to PHP can indeed never reach the `else` statement as it injects your page content in between.

Comment: Or, this sounds almost too simple to actually work, if you replace `@else` with `@if(Auth::user()->type != 'business')`

Answer (score 0):

Please can you update your OP to include the code for `<x-business-layout>`?

I believe your syntax error is being caused due to something there...

Alternatively, rather than having to duplicate the Page Content to be displayed  for each of your if statements, why not create a Function &/or Variable which contains the page's content to which you need only to call from within your if statements?

## Suggestion 1

```
      <!-- Variable Example -->
<?php
$someVariable = "PAGE CONTENT HERE";

?>
<!-- Function Example -->
<?php
function someFunction()
{
    $pageContent = "Example Page Content Here";
    return $pageContent;
}
?>

@if(Auth::user()->type == 'business')
    <x-business-layout>
        <?php
    //Variable Example
    echo $someVariable; 
    
    ?>
    </x-business-layout>
@else
    <x-app-layout>
        <?php
    //Function Example
    echo someFunction() 
    ?>
    </x-app-layout>
@endif
```

NOTE: `<?php` `?>` tags are only required if you are not already within open PHP tags!

## Suggestion 2:

```
@if(Auth::user()->type == 'business')
<x-business-layout>
@endif
@if(Auth::user()->type != 'business')
<x-app-layout>
@endif
    

    PAGE CONTENT HERE


@if(Auth::user()->type == 'business')
</x-business-layout>
@endif
@if(Auth::user()->type != 'business')
</x-app-layout>
@endif
```

Comment: You're asking more questions than the OP :) This doesn't help resolve the issue, thus shouldn't be posted as an answer.

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy what is wrong with what I have asked OP? It is a suggested answer to his question, which could help to resolve his issue...

Answer (score 0):

You can make a blade layout and extend it by your rules. for example:
Lets assume this is one of your layouts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  @section('content')
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the document you want to show:

```
@if(Auth::user()->type == 'business')
  @extends('layout1')
@else
  @extends('layout2')
@endif

@section('content')


 your content here


@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(Auth::user()->type == 'business')
<x-business-layout>
@if(Auth::user()->type != 'business')
<x-app-layout>
@endif
```

Your `@else` statement can never be reached as Laravel injects your page content in between the conditional block.

Answer (score 0):

Move page content to the partial view

```
@if (auth()->user()->type == 'business')
    <x-business-layout>
        @include('partials.page-content')
    </x-business-layout>
@else
    <x-app-layout>
        @include('partials.page-content')
    </x-app-layout>
@endif
```

or you can create `common` layout which will use template inheritance

**layouts/common.blade.php**

```
@if (auth()->user()->type == 'business')
    <x-business-layout>
        @yield('content')
    </x-business-layout>
@else
    <x-app-layout>
        @yield('content')
    </x-app-layout>
@endif
```

then you can use it in classic way

```
@extends('layouts.common')

@section('content')
    PAGE CONTENT HERE
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the conditional logic in a separate component:

##### components/layouts.blade.php

```html
@if(Auth::user()->type == 'business')
    <x-business-layout>{{ $slot }}</x-business-layout>
@else
    <x-app-layout>{{ $slot }}</x-app-layout>
@endif
```

And then use this component to encapsulate the different layout types:

##### password.blade.php

```html
<x-layout>
    PAGE CONTENT HERE
</x-layout>
```